# How to change x-axis?

Tags: c#, charts, graphic

friends! Today I want to ask you next question - how to change points on x-axis?

See what I have.

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 2;
...
for (double i = step; i <= T; i += step)
{...
   chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, SomeVar);
}
```

And so I have that.
[image]

But I don't want to see number 11. Can you understand me what I want? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the min max values of your axis, this will hide the auto generated axis labels.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
```

Comment: always a pleasure ;) Merry Christmas

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maximum and Minimum properties of AxisX here.